# Unity FBX "Export Textures" Checkbox Missing in FBX Exporter Window

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

The official docs here say "Textures can be embedded by selecting the "Embed Textures" option and "Binary" export format in the export settings on export."

(https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.fbx@4.2/manual/exporting.html#textures)

Using the latest version this checkbox is not visible on my system.  My prefab has textures that are showing up on the model...why is this option not showing up?

[image]

Comment: are you using 4.2 as it shows? as my unity shows fbx version 5, but then mine also shows export textures at the bottom